# Django 1.4 prefetch related does not keep results for inherited models

Tags: django, orm

I am trying to use prefetch related to keep Django from excessive queries, but I can't make it work for models with inheritance.

The problem is that when I traverse the model with the inheritance, the model instance is not cached and an SQL query is emitted.

I am not sure if this is a Django bug or am I misusing it somehow.

Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class ParentBase(models.Model): pass

class Parent(models.Model): pass

class ParentWithBase(ParentBase): pass

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent')
    parent_with_base = models.ForeignKey('ParentWithBase')
```

test case:

```
def test_prefetch_error(self):
    Child.objects.create(parent = Parent.objects.create(), parent_with_base = ParentWithBase.objects.create())
    child = Child.objects.prefetch_related('parent','parent_with_base').all()[0]
        with self.assertNumQueries(0):
            child.parent # This works just fine - no queries are emitted
        with self.assertNumQueries(0):
            child.parent_with_base # TEST FAILS HERE - since one query is emitted
```

Comment: I seem to have the same problem, did you reach any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19420 the fact that it doesn't cache this result has been fixed in Django 1.5.

But in this case, you could simply use `select_related` instead of `prefetch_related`. If you simply replace one with the other, your test passes.

`select_related` follows ForeignKey relationships. `prefetch_related` is more useful when you have many-to-many and many-to-one relationships, as it does a separate lookup for each relationship, and then does the 'joining' in Python. Using `select_related` would make just one DB call with joins, but `prefetch_related` will make multiple calls immediately, as it assumes it has to to do its thing.

Comment: Setting as answer, since you pointed out it works for 1.5.
I actually opened that ticket...
Using select_related is not really an option in my real use case, as it would cause too many JOINS, resulting with a giant result set.
This example was just the minimal repro I could find